# Tomcat - Exporting Private Key?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, ssl-certificate

So I've an appliance that uses SSL certs for different functions.

I generated a CSE using keytool using these commands:

keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /opt/msw/data/keystore -storepass changeit

keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /opt/msw/data/keystore -storepass changeit -file /root/certreq.csr

Which generated the CSR that I used to download the cert, then I installed it using

"keytool -import -alias tomcat -trustcacerts -keystore /opt/msw/data/keystore -storepass changeit -file /root/server.cert"

So far, so good.

However, one component that uses SSL requires both the certificate ***and*** the private key, which of course I don't have - and I don't see an obvious way using keytool to export the private key from Tomcat, is there one please?

Comment: This might be a silly question but how come 2 people have given me a "useful question" mark but nobody has given the guy that answered my question a "useful answer" mark - seems a little unfair :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe it or not, this functionality is not supported in keytool.  The best solution I have found so far is the software and instructions available for download on [this Web site.](http://www.anandsekar.com/2006/01/19/exporting-the-private-key-from-a-jks-keystore/)

I usually generate the key using openssl and then use [this method](http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html) to import the key, as that is not supported by keytool either.

To generate a 2048 bit key:

```
openssl genrsa -out host.domain.com.key 2048
```

To create a keystore from this key:

```
KEY=host.domain.com
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in $KEY.key -inform PEM -out key.der -outform DER
openssl x509 -in $KEY.crt -inform PEM -out cert.der -outform DER
wget http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/81/version/default/part/AttachmentData/data/ImportKey.class
java ImportKey key.der cert.der
```

Comment: Perfect, seems to have done the job just fine - thank you.